# Oracle convert HH:MI:SS to minutes?

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have a varchar2 column in an Oracle table called duration which has values such as 02:05:58 which is Hours:Minutes:Seconds. How can I convert this to minutes? IE: for the example shown have it display 125?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you ignoring the seconds value or should it be rounded? Can you have greater than 99 hours?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [date arithmetics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#i48042):

```
SQL> SELECT 24 * 60 * (to_date('02:05:58', 'HH24:MI:SS')
  2                    - TRUNC(to_date('02:05:58', 'HH24:MI:SS'))) min
  3    FROM dual;

       MIN
----------
125,966666
```

Comment: Assuming the OP's duration values don't exceed 23:59:59.

Comment: @GriffeyDog Yes, assuming also that the column is correctly formatted

Answer (score 0):

Simple function using SUBSTR.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION duration_in_minutes(
    p_duration IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  l_hours2minutes    NUMBER;
  l_minutes          NUMBER;
  l_seconds2minute   NUMBER;

BEGIN

  l_hours2minutes := to_number( substr( p_duration, 1, 2 ) ) * 60;
  l_minutes := to_number( substr( p_duration, 4, 2 ) );

  if to_number( substr( p_duration, 7, 2 ) ) < 30 then 
    l_seconds2minute := 0;
  else
  l_seconds2minute := 1;

  end if;

  return l_hours2minutes + l_minutes + l_seconds2minute;

END;
/
```